# MiniTest/Shoulda and Shoulda/Context reporting test methods?

Tags: ruby, minitest, shoulda

I am branching out from rspec and getting into MiniTest and shoulda. I can't figure out how test methods work with shoulda...

```
class TestKata <  MiniTest::Test
  context 'Kata#n00bify' do

    should 'replace "to" and "too" with the number 2, even if
            they are only part of a word (E.g. today = 2day)' do
      assert_equal '2', Kata.n00bify('too')
      assert_equal '2', Kata.n00bify('too')
      assert_equal '2day', Kata.n00bify('today')
    end

    should 'replace "for" and "fore" with the number 4' do
      assert_equal '4', Kata.n00bify('for')
      assert_equal '4', Kata.n00bify('fore')
    end

   # ...

  end
end
```

Here are the test results:

> ```
> Failure:
> TestKata#test_: Kata#n00bify should replace "for" and "fore" with the number 4.  [/.../test_n00b.rb:31]
> Minitest::Assertion: Expected: "4"
>   Actual: nil
>
>
> Failure:
> TestKata#test_: Kata#n00bify should replace "to" and "too" with the number 2, even if
>             they are only part of a word (E.g. today = 2day).  [/.../test_n00b.rb:25]
> Minitest::Assertion: Expected: "2"
>   Actual: nil
> ```

The thing that I don't understand is -- where are the test methods?  Notice in the test results its `TestKata#test_<nothing>:`.  Seems ugly to me.  Would love for it read with just the shoulda context. ie:

> ```
> Failure:
> Kata#n00bify should ...
> ```

What am I missing? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda provides an alternate syntax for defining test methods using `should` blocks.  Minitest requires test method names to start with the string `"test_"`, so Shoulda dynamically defines methods for each block using that convention.  When you write something like `should "foo"`, you get a test method named `test_: TestClassName#foo`.

As for the output, there are a ton of gems that implement alternate formatting.  You might try looking at minitest-reporters which is among the most full-featured and best maintained.